# Getting java.sql.SQLException in my code while I am fetching particular columns from DB table

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I am trying to use the **createSQLQuery** to fetch particular columns from DB. This query also uses **outer and inner joins**. Problem is when I am trying to assign that query into the list, it is showing SQLException. Below is the code:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<EmployeeLeaveRecord> empList=new ArrayList<EmployeeLeaveRecord>();
    SQLQuery query=session.createSQLQuery("SELECT a.id,a.applied_date,a.employee_id,d.name as EmpName,d.middlename as EmpMiddleName,d.lastname as EmpLastName,"
            + "c.leaveCategory,a.from_date,a.to_date,a.manager_status,a.approver_Id,b.name as ApproverFirstName,b.middlename as ApproverMidName,"
            + "b.lastname as ApproverLastName,a.num_of_leaves FROM lms_employee_leave_records a left outer join lms_employee b "
            + "on a.approver_Id=b.employee_id inner join lms_leave_category c on a.leave_category_id=c.id inner join lms_employee d "
            + "on a.employee_id=d.employee_id where a.employee_status !='CANCELLED' order by a.applied_date desc;");

    query.addEntity(EmployeeLeaveRecord.class);
    empList = query.list();
    System.out.println("AFTR------------emplist size = "+empList.size());
    for (Iterator iterator = empList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            EmployeeLeaveRecord employeeLeaveRecord = (EmployeeLeaveRecord) iterator.next();

            System.out.println("No. of leaves are:"+employeeLeaveRecord.getNumOfLeaves());

    }

    session.close();
    return empList ;
```

And here is the exception:

```
Oct 07, 2016 7:11:43 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
Oct 07, 2016 7:11:43 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logEx``ceptions
SEVERE: Column 'emp_reason' not found.
Oct 07, 2016 7:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DigiLMS] in context with path [/DigiLMS] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'emp_reason' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5729)
```

Here is my class file for **EmployeeLeaveRecord** :

```
        public EmployeeLeaveRecord(EmployeeStatus empStatus, Date fromDate, Date toDate,
            LeaveCategory leaveCategory, ManagerStatus managerStatus, Date appliedDate, Employee employee,Employee approver,/* String name,*/
            String source, Date managerApprovalDate, String empReason, float numOfLeaves) {
        super();
        this.empStatus = empStatus;
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
        this.toDate = toDate;
        this.leaveCategory = leaveCategory;
        this.managerStatus = managerStatus;
        this.appliedDate = appliedDate;
        this.employee = employee;
        //this.name = name;
        this.source = source;
        this.managerApprovalDate = managerApprovalDate;
        this.empReason = empReason;
        this.numOfLeaves = numOfLeaves;
        this.approver = approver;
    }
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server? That are two different things

Comment: What are your hibernate mappings for `EmployeeLeaveRecord` ?

Comment: @Berger EmployeeLeaveRecord has ManyToOne Mapping with Employee.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not include the emp_reason column in its projection. Since your object constructor expects that, Hibernate is trying to find that column in the result set when calling the constructor (thus you're getting that exception). Adding emp_reason to the select statement in the query should fix it.

Comment: I do't want to fetcch emp_reason. How it can be done now?

Comment: Remove it from the EmployeeLeaveRecord object or add `NULL as emp_reason` to the query,